# Can't locate a file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, web

I am new to Node.js and while following one of the tutorials at tutorialspoint http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm
I tried to run one simple program, but I am unable to run it successfully

```
var fs = require("fs");
var data = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt');
console.log(data.toString());
console.log("Program Ended");
```

This is the error message which I get:

```
C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Nodee>node main.js
fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Nodee\input.txt'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Nodee\main.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

Here is the Screenshot of my folder inside my desktop
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz5a0.png

I have used this path but it failed as well:

```
C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Nodee
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's `input.txt` and not `input.txt.txt`?

Comment: In your screenshot the `.js` of your javascript file is not shown, that means the file extensions are not shown, so your file is probably named `input.txt.txt`

Comment: Thanks a lot, such a silly mistake. :(       It is working fine now.